# Python: How to append to dict without "key"?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, append

I have a python function which returns a dict. Now I want to call this function various times and append all these returned dicts to the first one.

```
def generate_dict(greeting):
    n = len(greeting)
    i = int(np.random.random()*(n-1))
    j = int(np.random.random()*(n-1))
    text = greeting[i] + greeting[j]
    start = text.find(greeting[i])
    return {"text": text,
            "Intention": "Greet",
            "entity": [
                {
                     "start": start,
                     "end": start + len(greeting[i]),
                     "value": greeting[i],
                     "entity": "Hello"
                }
            ],
           }

greeting = ['Hallo', 'Hey', 'Hi']

dict1 = generate_dict(greeting)
for k in range(1,10):
    dict1[k] = generate_dict(greeting)

print dict1
```

This code gives me as a result something like:

```
{1: {'text': 'HeyHey', 'entity': [{'start': 0, 'end': 3, 'value': 'Hey', 'entity': 'Hello'}], 'Intention': 'Greet'}, 2: {'text': 'HeyHallo', 'entity': [{'start': 0, 'end': 3, 'value': 'Hey', 'entity': 'Hello'}], 'Intention': 'Greet'}, 3: {'text': 'HeyHallo', 'entity': [{'start': 0, 'end': 3, 'value': 'Hey', 'entity': 'Hello'}], 'Intention': 'Greet'}, 4: {'text': 'HeyHallo', 'entity': [{'start': 0, 'end': 3, 'value': 'Hey', 'entity': 'Hello'}], 'Intention': 'Greet'}, ... }
```

But I would like to get:

```
{'text': 'HeyHey', 'entity': [{'start': 0, 'end': 3, 'value': 'Hey', 'entity': 'Hello'}], 'Intention': 'Greet'},{'text': 'HeyHallo', 'entity': [{'start': 0, 'end': 3, 'value': 'Hey', 'entity': 'Hello'}], 'Intention': 'Greet'},{'text': 'HeyHallo', 'entity': [{'start': 0, 'end': 3, 'value': 'Hey', 'entity': 'Hello'}], 'Intention': 'Greet'},{'text': 'HeyHallo', 'entity': [{'start': 0, 'end': 3, 'value': 'Hey', 'entity': 'Hello'}], 'Intention': 'Greet'}, ...
```

How can I archieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want a list to store these data, maybe you can try:

```
dict1= [generate_dict(greeting) for k in range(1,10)]
```

dict1:

```
[{'text': 'HalloHallo', 'entity': [{'start': 0, 'end': 5, 'value': 'Hallo', 'entity': 'Hello'}], 'Intention': 'Greet'}, 
{'text': 'HalloHey', 'entity': [{'start': 0, 'end': 5, 'value': 'Hallo', 'entity': 'Hello'}], 'Intention': 'Greet'}, 
{'text': 'HeyHallo', 'entity': [{'start': 0, 'end': 3, 'value': 'Hey', 'entity': 'Hello'}], 'Intention': 'Greet'}...]
```

Comment: @Judith have a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work